# can a router alter ports?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

i want to have a router change the port that it directs the traffic to. is it possible?
say - WAN port 1000 to LAN port 2000. in many router's forwarding screen it appears possible, but i've never done this and don't know if it will work. googling brings up a lot of port forwarding tutorials, but nothing on changing the port.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "port forwarding" can rewrite the destination ports in addition to addresses. Routers implementing NAT already need to rewrite TCP/UDP ports for outbound packets and their inbound responses (in case two LAN hosts happen to talk to the same remote service using the same local port), so they can use the exact same mechanism for manually-configured inbound "port forwarding" rules as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the router, of course, but good routers offer port forwarding rules and setup.

Log into the router, go to the Firewall, thence to Port Forwarding and add your rules.

[image]

Comment: ok, thanks. will try.